# Zend Passing variable to PartialLoop inside partial view

Tags: php, zend-framework, partial-views

I have in my view a partial containing a partialLoop.
But when I run the page I have the following error message:

```
Call to a member function countComments() on a non-object in ...'_loop.phtml'
```

This is how I call my partial from within my view:

```
echo $this->partial('_post.phtml',$this->post);
```

where $this->post is a DB retrieved row

This is **my partial's** content:

```
MY simplified Partial! 

echo $post->countComments();//the count number is correctly output..
echo  $this->partialLoop('_loop.phtml',$this->object);
```

This is **my partialLoop's** content:

```
echo $this->object->countComments();//no output!
```

In the **bootstrap** I have set:

```
$view->partial()->setObjectKey('object');
$view->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('object');
```

**Is this the right way to call partialLoops from within partials??**

**P.s.** I var_dumped $this->object inside my partial and it is a PostRow OBJECT.I var dumped $this->object into _loop.phtml and I have 5 NULLS (standing for id,title,text,author,datetime fields of my post)

thanks

Luca

Comment: What is this: `echo $post->countComments();`. Shouldn't this be `echo $post->object->countComments();` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the reason is that when you pass `$this->post` into partial view helper like this:

```
$this->partial('_post.phtml',$this->post);
```

partial view helper will execute its `toArray()` method. Hence, your `$this->object` is an array and you are passing an array to your partialLoop. So, in your partialLoop you are trying to execute `countComments()` on an array representing your row post object, rather than actual row object.

To avoid this, I would recommend passing variables to partial and partialLoop view helpers using array notation, e.g:

```
$this->partial('_post.phtml',array('post' => $this->post));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I var_dumped $this->object: inside partial is a PostRow Object.Inside the partialLoop is NULL.Relying on your answer shouldnt I see an array??thanks

Comment: Actually inside the partial loop var_dump($this->object) outputs 5 NULLS (I think they stands for id,title,text,author,datetime fields of my post row)

Comment: I solved thanks but still confused about what I actually did by passing the variables using array notation.Any further explaination would be really appreciated!

Comment: @luca. So how did you solve it? Sorry, I have no more clues what would be the cause for the initial problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused by the default behaviour of the `partial` and `partialLoop` view helpers as Marcin said above.
Although it is confusing the manual does explain this [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

> Object implementing toArray() method. If an object is passed an has a
>   toArray() method, the results of toArray() will be assigned to the
>   view object as view variables.

The solution is to explicitly tell the partial to pass the object. As the manual explains:

```
// Tell partial to pass objects as 'model' variable
$view->partial()->setObjectKey('model');   
// Tell partial to pass objects from partialLoop as 'model' variable 
// in final partial view script: 
$view->partialLoop()->setObjectKey('model');
```

> This technique is particularly useful when passing
>   Zend_Db_Table_Rowsets to partialLoop(), as you then have full access
>   to your row objects within the view scripts, allowing you to call
>   methods on them (such as retrieving values from parent or dependent
>   rows).